# How to create your own Android Library (implementation) in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Example: I want to design a button in Android Studio. I want to use this button in 3 projects, but I don't want to create 3 times. How to create my own implementation for button or bottom navigation bar...

Answer (score -1):

1. Create your library module ([the official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#CreateLibrary))
2. Import that library module into another project ([the official guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#AddDependency))

Comment: if i create button or layout, drawable can i use them on new my own projects?  (R.layout.example).Thanks